# Why linear gradient is applied to just 1% of the page (CSS)?

Tags: html, css

When I tried to apply the linear gradient to a page in html using html tag in css the result is many tight strips, each one has it's own gradient.

```
html

    {
    background-image:linear-gradient(to top, black, white);
    }
```

[image]
but when I specified the height to be 100% it was applied to the hole page:

```
html
{background-image:linear-gradient(to top, black, white);
height:100%;
}
```

[image]
and when I specified the height to be 1% the result was the same strips with same height.
[image]

I'm confused and I don't know the reason behind that and why by default it's applied to just 1% despite I use the html tag (the root tag)?

Comment: what you want to achieve .?

Comment: I think that CSS use the same criteria with background color, but we can't notice that cause it's just one color!

Comment: The job is done by specifying the height to be 100%.. I just want to know the theory!

Comment: The theory is: Default height of html is not 100%

Comment: This is strange and interesting, it seems to be repeated depending of the height of `<html>` but adding a `overflow: hidden;` do not change anything

Comment: there are lots of `html` element when its `height` is not defined, have you tried setting it to `50%`, do you see two stripes now??

Comment: I think when you define your html it's default height is `8px` because, if you inspect `html` element in Chrome - you can see that it's `8px`. Then by default `background` repeat by `x` and `y`, so you can see a lot of lines in your.

Comment: @MohammedElshawaf it's due the `body` margin, which isn't 0 by default. If you put `body{margin: 0}` then it won't work.

Comment: Thanks all.
I think that it depends on the content, and because there is no content yet, just blank page then it's set to minimum height.. now I added a logo and changed its padding properties, the stripes height automatically changed to fit the new content.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `background-image` but `background` only, and add `background-attachment`.

If You use `background-image` and set `height:100%` for `html` while scrolling, You'll lose gradients.

Try this (just `background` and without `height`):

```
html
{
    background:linear-gradient(to top, black, white);
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `html` is not full height. It is probably something like eight pixels tall. So setting the background image to a linear gradient executes that gradient over eight pixels. The default behavior for background images is to repeat indefinitely. That is why the eight pixel gradient is repeated over and over.

If you add `background-repeat: no-repeat` you'll see just one small gradient, and if you set the height to `100%` you'll see the gradient expand to fill the element.